# make hover to img tag with jQuery chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm currently trying this. But it isn't working..

```
$('.hover-button').hover(function() {
    $('.section.coolClass img').addClass('.hoverclass');
});
```

Because assuming it's attaching to the img tag and failing. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**YES**. On hover out, the class needs to be removed..

Also, **note:** I am trying to achieve this:

```
section.coolClass img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2); z-index: 3; cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: HTML in example please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `css` when you should be using `toggleClass`. Like this:

```
$('.hover-button').hover(function() {
    $('.section.coolClass img').toggleClass('hoverclass');
});
```

`css` is used to add inline styles to your elements. When you want to add/remove classes to your elements use `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass`. Also don't include the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.hover-button').hover(function() {
    $('.section.coolClass img').toggleClass('hoverclass');
});
```